# How to pass a value from mapStateToProps into a function?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make the following link inaccessible if a user is not logged in:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/page" exact component={page}/>
```

React returns an error on this code:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        this.props.isAuthenticated === true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to='/login'/>
    )}/>
);
```

And the `is.Authenticated` part

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.token !== null
    };
};
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

I am trying to access the `isAuthenticated` passed from my `mapStateToProps` in the function `PrivateRoute`, how can I do that ?

Comment: replace `this.props` by `rest`

Comment: Can you share the full code of `PrivateRoot` to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created my answer in combination of @Emanuele and @Sultan.

So First I changed my `PrivateRoute` from

```
<PrivateRoute path="/page" exact component={page}/>
```

to

```
<PrivateRoute path="/page" exact component={page} auth={this.props.isAuthenticated}/>
```

This way I can pass the value from `mapStateToProps` in the `PrivateRoute`

Then I edited the function `PrivateRoute` to get the value of auth from the `PrivateRoute`. It now looks like follows

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (

    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (

        rest.auth !== false
            ? <Component {...props}/>
            : <Redirect to='/'/>
    )}/>
);
```

And now the `privateRoute` function is aware of the `isAuthenticated` value passed from the connect

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use `rest` instead of this.props (which is not defined)

```
rest.isAuthenticated === true
```

and not:

```
this.props.isAuthenticated === true
```

Then you have to pass the prop to the private route, something like this:

```
<PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={some_variable_here}> // According to your validation logic
```

Comment: the `isAuthenticated` part is toggled by the `state` defined in `mapStateToProps`, so by passing it manually, I am bypassing the authentication. Therefore, I am trying to pass the `isAuthenticated` that is coming from `mapStateToProps` instead of the `rest`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => (
        !!rest.isAuthenticated === true
            ? <Component {...rest} />
            : <Redirect to='/login'/>
    )}/>
);
```

Comment: I would like to dig into it, can you edit the question and include the whole code for the PrivateRoute? wanna make sure data is available as it should, also the logic is correctly implemented.

Comment: Yes exactly, especially, I want to make sure that in your Root Reducer, you have `token` attribute, which you are using as `state.token !== null` to calculate `isAuthenticated` at `mapStateToProps`, can you confirm that the root reducer already has an attribute `token` which resolves a valid value in case of logged in users?

Comment: Looking to the reducer you have, the condition should possibly be `state.authReducer.token !== null`, `authReducer` is the name you actually define at `rootReducer` which is given as the first parameter to the `createStore` function.

Comment: If I use `state.authReducer.token` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`, however when I pass `state`, and use `state.token` then I get the token. Thing is, I still can see the page although I am not logged in (token is null) according to Redux DevTool

Comment: I have updated the answer, added `!!` before `rest.isAuthenticated === true` just to make sure that it actually holds a valid value. example: `!!null` will return `false`, `!!'somestring'` will return `true`.

Comment: This might solve the `it still opens while token is null`, but, I still need to see the _rootReducer_, you can find it at `reducers/index.js` or `reducers/rootReducer.js` it's basically the file where you export `combineReducers` object.

Comment: As I can see the `token` has a value in the `redux_devtools`, I can only assume that the `state.token !== null` is not getting updated when I log in on the browser. That is why I was trying to make the function  `const PrivateRoute`, access the `isAuthenticated` from the `mapStateToProps`

Comment: I see now the `console.log(state.token)` returns undefined

Comment: I suspect it doesnt exist, can you tell me what are you passing to `createStore` function as the first parameter? Should be at a file called `store.js`

Comment: Sultan, the issue is not in the reducer. The issue is me trying to pass the value `isAuthenticated` from `mapStateToProps` to a function `PrivateRoute`. Basically, how can I pass the `token` value into the function `privateRoute` ?

Comment: There are multiple steps to do that, first: write the reducer, second: pass the reducer to the root reducer which is connected to the store, third: `connect(null, mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)` which will get the value stored in the reducer you have defined in the root reducer, and inject it to the props of the component, the problem actually can be at one of the 3 steps.

Comment: Hi I think I fixed it , check my answer

Comment: Good job. I guess you don't have `connect()()` part at your `PrivateRoute` Component correct?

Comment: thank you Sir, nothing fancy. The function is in the same page as the app